# Have XeLaTeX use the default Times font in Ubuntu

Tags: fonts, xetex, pdf

Using the [Texlive PPA backport](https://launchpad.net/~texlive-backports/+archive/ppa) to Ubuntu 12.04, I am having trouble getting XeLaTeX to use a standard times font (i.e. one that would not be embedded).

I am using e.g. `\setmainfont{times}` and `\newfontfamily\fontfamilyname{Times}`, and have installed the `texlive-fonts-recommended` package, which says (in the `apt-cache show texlive-fonts-recommended`):

```
 times -- Select Adobe Times Roman (or equivalent) as default font.
 timesnew -- the URW Times fonts and support for the Adobe font set.
```

When I run xelatex on a tex file that tries to use the fonts above, I get a long list of errors, many like the following:

```
Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
 ...e:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input times

Transcript written on mfput.log.
grep: times.log: No such file or directory
mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input times'
 failed to make times.tfm.

kpathsea: Running mktextfm times
/usr/share/texlive/texmf/web2c/mktexnam: Could not map source abbreviation  for times.
/usr/share/texlive/texmf/web2c/mktexnam: Need to update ?
mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input times
This is METAFONT, Version 2.718281 (TeX Live 2012/Debian)
```

I would be grateful for thoughts on how to use the standard Times font in PDFs created with XeLaTeX on Ubuntu.

---

**EDIT** Sorry I didn't post the example earlier -- had to put the little one to bed, and I had hoped this was a mind-numbingly simple oversight on my part :)

Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\setmainfont{Times}
\begin{document}
 In Times we trust.
\end{document}
```

Here is what XeLaTeX responds with:

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
! 
! The font "Times" cannot be found.
! 
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................
```

One solution that occurs to me is to manually install an OTF or TTF font that is a substitute for Times, but I would expect that the texlive distribution or Ubuntu otherwise has that - but it is not immediately apparent where.

Comment: Can you please show a minimal example of what you're trying?

Comment: XeTeX can use system font using the `fontconfig` library. Can you try the shell command `fc-list|grep Times` and add the result to your question?

Comment: Thanks @egreg - I do not have a Times font installed as an OTF or TTF. I would be grateful for suggestions about where one might find it. I did try Libertine Serif (as it is described in the package as having the same font metrics as Times), but it was also embedded.

Comment: You should have TeX Gyre Termes, which is a Times clone: `\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}` might do.

Comment: Thanks @egreg, but alas I can confirm that both Tex Gyre Termes and even a Times truetype font are embedded in the PDF, according to popper-utils' pdffonts (and same is evident from the file size).

Comment: XeTeX (better, the driver `xdvipdfmx`) always embeds the fonts in the PDF. But the same is true for all TeX programs: I believe that relying on the "default" font is not even recommended by Adobe.

Comment: @egreg: I think you're right, based on what I'd been reading too. I'd mark that correct if you posted it as an answer. :)

Comment: @BrianM.Hunt So what you really want is that the document uses the build-in Times of any viewer and does not contain an embedded Times font?

Comment: @egreg: The embedding of font can be configured (at least for pdfTeX and luaTeX, and I believe for XeTeX also). It's all in the map files. `updmap setoption pdftexDownloadBase14 false` should force the pdf producing TeX engines to not download Times Type1 fonts (and the 13 other base fonts).

Comment: @BrianM.Hunt: what is the reason _not_ to embed a subset of the fonts?

Comment: @Herbert - I wanted to use the builtin fonts just to decrease the size of the PDF.

Comment: @BrianM.Hunt: that makes no real sense for a Times of Type 1 format, too less space saving. However, you can use the GhostScript fonts, if you have installed GS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, the 14 base fonts that all PDF readers should know are Type1 fonts (Times, Courier, Helvetica, Symbol and Zapf Dingbats) and they *don't* support arbitrary Unicode.

So, while with `(pdf)latex` it would be possible to avoid downloading the base fonts in a PDF document by setting the corresponding option

```
updmap-sys setoption pdftexDownloadBase14 false
updmap-sys setoption dvipsDownloadBase14 false
```

(thanks to Martin Schröder for pointing to the command, see the man page of `updmap` for more information; end with `true` for reverting to the default), this has little sense with XeLaTeX, because it would deprive it of its main feature, that is, dealing with OpenType or TrueType fonts covering the whole Unicode character set.

Thus, if you plan to use XeLaTeX for exploiting OpenType features, let XeTeX and `xdvipdfmx` download the font to the PDF file.

Comment: It isn't clear from this answer how you let XeTeX and `dvipdfmx` download a font to a PDF file...

Comment: @sautedman They do it automatically

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu (as every Linux system) does not have Times font installed, but comes with a number of alternatives; the popular are:

- PT Serif (excellent Cyrillic support)
- FreeSerif
- Droid Serif (Android default)
- (Linux) Libertine Serif
- DejaVu Serif

Just check with `fc-list|grep Serif` and choose one of your liking.

Comment: Thanks Alexander. Unfortunately this answer does not resolve the _sine qua non_ element of the question: "[get] XeLaTeX to use a standard times font (i.e. **one that would not be embedded**)"